# Is there any way to dial a number without a tel protocol?

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement for Device 4.0 like, User dial a number from my app and then app should connect to that number. At the mean time I need a handler to keep track the stateChanges for the call(To do so I can use core telephony APIs).

So can any know how can a number be connected without a "tel" protocol.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way to dial a number is to use tel:123123123
You could use CTCallCenter callEventHandler property so set an event handler and receive it if your app is active.

From the docs:

> If your application is active when a
>   call event takes place, the system
>   dispatches the event to your handler
>   immediately. However, call events can
>   also take place while your application
>   is suspended. While it is suspended,
>   your application does not receive call
>   events. When your application resumes
>   the active state, it receives a single
>   call event for each call that changed
>   state—no matter how many state changes
>   the call experienced while your
>   application was suspended. The single
>   call event sent to your handler, upon
>   your application returning to the
>   active state, describes the call’s
>   state at that time.

BTW: There is no way to prevent your application to be suspended. The OS will suspend it without notification when memory is needed.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! yeah well can you help me to find a idea for "Where the app dials a number, as soon as it connects the app should resume to active state."